# How can I have multiple post request handling methods in a Class Based View

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

The docs suggest that I can have one get, post, put method in a Class Based View. How can I implement something like this?

```
class Test(APIView):
    def post_modelA(request):
        # code to create instances for model A
    def post_modelB(request):
        # code to create instances for model B
```

Comment: you don't have to. You can handle in a single post. Only check what is in the post data and perform actions.

Comment: I have same problem. Did you find right answer?

Comment: As Sandeep said, you can simply look into the flask.request object and perform actions according to that

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps extend `GenericViewSet` and provide your own actions mapping in the `urls.py`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('test/modelA', views.Test.as_view({'post': 'post_modelA'})),
    path('test/modelB', views.Test.as_view({'post': 'post_modelB'})),
]
```

Comment: interesting, do you have a reference to a example?

Comment: the [official documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)
with example `user_list = UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})`

Answer (score 0):

You can write two class based views

```
class TestA(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        # code to create instances for model A

 class TestB(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        # code to create instances for model B
```

Comment: class is meant to group endpoints. like: /users/endpoint1 /users/endpoint2 /users/endpoint3 etc. You should have one UsersClass then. check instagram as an example: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/